# Need some help with jquery plugin select2 and VF page

Tags: visualforce, jquery, java

I am trying to use jquery plugin [select2](https://select2.github.io/) in my VF page to make the select look better. For some reason i cant get it to work.

I have loaded in all the js and css as static resources. There is no error on the console, but the select just shows the normal ui box with options in it.

```
    <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.select2, '/js/jquery-2.1.0.js')}"/>
     <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.select2, '/js/select2.js')}"/> 

<apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.select2, '/css/select2.min.css')}" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $('select').select2();
    </script>
```

and my select is

```
<select  data-placeholder="Type to search Targetting"  multiple="multiple" >
                            <apex:repeat value="{!s.TargetingOptions}" var="stage">
                               <option value="{!stage.value}">{!stage.label}</option> 
                            </apex:repeat>
                        </select>
```

Any thoughts on what am i missing? I am not stuck with this plugin, i am ok as long as i am able to get something neat and allows multiple selections

Comment: There is a small chance that you are invoking `$('select').select2();` before the element is in the DOM; its usual to use [ready](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) to avoid that risk as in the first example in [examples](https://select2.github.io/examples.html).

Comment: You nailed it. I have been spending hours to find what the issue was. Thank you. If you can add it as an answer so i can accept it

Comment: Good that you've got it sorted. Added as an answer.

Comment: note also best practice to use something other than `$` to avoid VF conflicts - https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Developing_Apps_with_jQuery

Comment: Thanks @crop1645 i have used `jQuery.noConflict()` in my code now :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a small chance that you are invoking `$('select').select2();` before the element is in the DOM; it's usual to use [ready](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) to avoid that risk as in the first example in the select2 [examples](https://select2.github.io/examples.html). (Though it's a pity not all the examples follow that pattern.)

**PS**

Combining Sebastian's answer with crop1645's comment about `$` and avoiding adding to the global namespace (and also suggesting that all the JavaScript should usually be added at the end of the Visualforce):

```
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.select2, '/js/jquery-2.1.0.js')}"/>
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.select2, '/js/select2.js')}"/>
<script>
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('select').select2();
    });
})(jQuery.noConflict());
</script>
```

Comment: I upvoted, Keith, but wanted to provide a specific example for the OP, since he didn't mark your question as answered.

Comment: Nice self executing anonymous function!

Answer (score 3):

Try this as your javascript code, it is better to run your JS code in your `document.ready` function that just dropping it in the script tag.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('select').select2();
});
```